# What do the following parameters indicate in a resettable fuse?

Tags: power-supply, power, protection, circuit-protection, fuses

I am not sure how to decipher the Pd and R1max info in the below [datasheet](https://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs2/2018/5/21/19/21/41/613/ltf_/auto/85littelfuse_ptc_smd_catalog_datasheet.pdf.pdf).

[image]

Does PD indicate the tripped state power dissipation or maximum power dissipation under non-tripped operation?

If you calculate the Pd for normal operation (for the highlighted row) , it is (0.5^2)*Rmin ~ 0.0625W. How can the power during the tripped condition (0.8W) be so high? Does it mean the fuse will not trip (rather limits the current to 1A) and starts drawing 0.8W for its own heating?

Another [document](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/resettable_ptcs/littelfuse_ptc_lvr_catalog_datasheet.pdf.pdf) from same manufacturer, Rmax and Pd indicate the following.

[image]

[image]

Looking at the R1max after 1 hour, it looks like the fuse takes significant time to cool down (or bring the resistance down) to restart the operation.

Is this high delay inherent for all resettable fuses?

Comment: @Rohit : Sorry, My bad! Corrected relay to fuse